# Must declare the scalar variable "@unwantedRows"

Tags: sql-server-2008

Why is this query not working?

```
Delete  tblProduct
From    tblProduct
Inner Join @unwantedRows
On tblProduct.ProductId = @unwantedRows.ProductId;
```

Where `@unwantedRows` is

```
DECLARE @unwantedRows TABLE 
( 
    ProductId INT, 
    ProductName VARCHAR(50),
    Description VARCHAR(50),
    Category VARCHAR(50),
    Repetitions int

);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the variable name in the join like that.

Try:

```
Delete  tblProduct
From    tblProduct
Inner Join @unwantedRows AS u
On tblProduct.ProductId = u.ProductId;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Delete  tblProduct
From    tblProduct
WHERE tblProduct.ProductId IN (SELECT ProductId FROM @unwantedRows);
```